# Change column name with file name of corresponding excel file

Tags: r, excel

I have 100 excel files in one folder and I would like to change the name of the fourth column of each file to corresponding file name in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  #Read the data
  data <- readxl::read_excel(x)
  #Change the 4th column with filename
  names(data)[4] <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
  #Write the data back
  writexl::write_xlsx(data, x)
})
```

Comment: Many thanks. How to modify this part : writexl::write_xlsx(data, x) to have a file .xls instead of .xlsx ?

Comment: `writexl::write_xlsx(data, sub('xlsx$', 'xls', x))`

Comment: Sorry a question again: instead of overwriting the file, is it possible to create a new one?

Comment: `writexl::write_xlsx(data, sub('\\.xlsx$', '_new.xls', x))`

Comment: The file is still overwritten. The problem with this method is that it creates a corrupted excel file

Comment: @Cordyline Please ask that as a new question as this is not actually related to your original question.