# Corrupted/overwritten excel file with write_xlsx

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I am using this code in R to change the name of the fourth column of an excel file (thanks to this: [Change column name with file name of corresponding excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769828/change-column-name-with-file-name-of-corresponding-excel-file)), however the problem is that at the end the file is overwritten and it generates a corrupted excel file (Excel file format and extension don’t match). How it is possible to create a new excel file a the end (not overwritten) or do you have any other solution to not create a corrupted file?

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  #Read the data
  data <- readxl::read_excel(x)
  #Change the 4th column with filename
  names(data)[4] <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
  #Write the data back
  writexl::write_xlsx(data, x)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tools::file_path_sans_ext` and `tools:.file_ext` to put together a new output filename. In the code below, I append the suffix `_new` to the file name before the file extension.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)

lapply(filenames, function(x) {
  #Read the data
  data <- readxl::read_excel(x)
  #Change the 4th column with filename
  y <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
  names(data)[4] <- y
  #Write the data back
  ext <- tools::file_ext(x)
  y <- paste0(y, "_new.", ext)
  writexl::write_xlsx(data, y)
})
```

Comment: The file generated is still corrupted. The problem comes from that my initial excel files extension are .xls (filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xls', full.names = TRUE). Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Cordyline Function `xlsx::write.xlsx` writes both xls and xlsx files. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Function `xlsx::write.xlsx` works well indeed. However the file generated is corrupted. You can open the file in excel, however you have an error message : Excel file format and extension don’t match. If you want to read this files in R with `readxl::read_excel(.x)`  you have this error message : libxls error: Unable to open file